# JPA Inheritance: MappedSuperclass or Join?

Tags: java, oop, jpa

I have the following situation: an online medical monitoring system which has three types of users (entities): **Doctor**, **Caregiver** and **Patient**. Each of these users will login using credentials, so I thought about a superclass **User**. The doctor's role is to give the patient a medication plan, which the caregiver will help administrate.

After a user logs in, it should redirect him to his corresponding page (depending on his role).

What type of JPA Inheritance should I use? I thought about using `@MappedSuperclass`, since the superclass **User** has no relationship with the others classes from the database (e.g. **MedicalPlan**, **Drugs**), just its subclasses. Will I be able to model `many-to-many` relationships between the subclasses this way (e.g. a doctor is assigned to many patients and a patient may have received a medical plan from many doctors)?

Comment: Yes, why couldn't you? Note that in real life, doctors also need to go to the doctor sometimes, so they can be patients too. Or patients can go to the school and become doctors. So if you need to model this kind of real situation, inheritance is not the right tool. Also note that MappedSuperclass won't allow you, for example, to create a LoginAttempt entity with a ManyToOne with a User. So MappedSuperclass is probably not the right solution either.

Comment: @JBNizet Is the LoginAttempt entity with a ManyToOne with a User needed in case a User has more than one role (e.g. a user is a doctor but also a caregiver)? Because I am not looking to implement it that way, I am looking to a single role per user

Comment: Even if users have only one role, if the 3 classes extend from User and User is not an entity, but a MappedSuperclass, then you can not have any association with a User (such as, for example a LoginAttempt) You also can't have a unique constraint on User.login, for example: all users would be stored in 3 separate, unrelated tables.

Comment: @JBNizet ah ok, I understood. So by going with MappedSuperclass I can't have anything related to the User superclass. What would be the best alternative, considering I am looking to a many-to-many relationship between Doctor and Patient (and thus needing ID columns to join the tables)?

Comment: Make User an Entity. I'd go with the default inheritance strategy too: SINGLE_TABLE.